# TypeError...is not a function

Tags: typescript

I have a simple `User` class with a `toJSON` function

```
class User {
  username: string;
  photoUrl: string;

  constructor(username: string, photoUrl: string) {
    this.username = username;
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
  }

  toJSON(): any {
    let json = {
      username: this.username,
      photoUrl: this.photoUrl,
    };
    return json;
  }
}
```

And another class `Notification` with its own `toJSON` function which tries to call `User.toJSON` but I'm getting the runtime error `TypeError: user.toJSON is not a function`?

```
class Notification {
  users: User[]
  
  constructor(
    users: User[],
  ) {
    this.users = users
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    console.log(">>> adding user ", user.toJSON())
    this.users.push(user)
  }

  toJSON(): any {
    const usersJSON: any = [];
    this.users.forEach((user: User) => {
      usersJSON.push(user.toJSON())
    // swapping the line above with the line below works fine
    //usersJSON.push({ username: user.username, photoUrl: user.photoUrl });
  })

  let json = {
    users: usersJSON,
  };

  return json
}
```

The weird thing (for me) is the toJSON call works fine elsewhere, it just fails within `Notification.toJSON`?

EDIT

Created a sample running my code on [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBYo4BoeMheRDwAYMEHsGjfNxmZjsBjMSD8WDQdSJZnwPQiLwAIgAoqsGIgavoJUkcRLwA5UAByYQAOUgEglQRUAHlvmRdoI%20VpIMdUI4FK5pHhQE4GTpRlh9CgEIgYcIruyJIzoiIDBwcd0WGwuNwgiUBQxBMIHhacQBvRQldgpzhyyD5a6oSicZgAbgz1Uww3gDzI0HzgkLozL5YQnAbZHYsHQZAAFFmfjnkPXG8X%20ARK%20ga3WC0XmABKUDpkolEaCAL9um50AAXlAG8HkDLy4Ea-HVanO4r59rR9AAF9giv4AApYhG7U9uf5sxOpfL9w0AAVoI8BeLuf7Hvuub5qu67ZrmvDlseZ6TrWMFqKeE7VrWiHHg%20x5OASdKgMBoHlg%20D6KPGiagAAsng2rDIi6j4hQoGLuWG4FI8KYANoALrli2oHtp23Y9khe4ptxyY-AJuGgAuEEnnBPzCLuXHkY%20YjcNwsm9hu%20b6UpkmtiB7gBNA8DMD2EoAHwOTpCLFlJPygBK-AbgE6Cvu%20n5zpJsFcQEBBZpgfYpgFJSUU%20vkfl%20YicL%20pkiTQXFxd%20SWXgJt4rhhqm-AEySMlKPThRFPxGZFO52Rxx6ZtJcUhWFFVkN5L5vvFUXLiogi5AQmIueygqcM4IJih8mjDRkKDSDA8ASJIjLxMIyQzZJIDpZ1zX2D2qauZuQ4HQVB5jlhU75l5KHYdA95zrld3aQBJEgWBdXLlxl2NZ1CkxcuhGEl4pGcFplFmWlKYAAyXqNi36bZz7wJgnAee50iMJgEoBeDgxMWtsCsexu6w3RDF4yxqBsZwPa8RukP8QFQyU-jhOcAEDC6fDJPwxKxDsJAqMSujDCY3O2MifAFlWTZEpM8xBOU6B%20ao3LLOK2zPmdf5QA) and it runs fine there. Will investigate more and post what I learn

Comment: What is `this.users` supposed to be?

Comment: @Aplet123 Sorry, got carried away with my code pruning. Just added it

Comment: Where do you set `this.users`? Do you do any non type-safe assignments (such as assigning an `any` to one of the elements)?

Comment: @Aplet123 I'm new to TS. Doesn't `users: User[]` set it?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys By doing this.users.forEach, you are iterating the user objects in this.users. So, the list must be populated somewhere right?

Comment: If this is your real code, you have a : before the declaration of toJSON. This seem not valid to me. Maybe this causes the error.

Comment: @Nikolaus Sorry, was using the `:` to show code was removed for clarity. Change the OP to put it in a comment

Comment: @Sabareesh Sorry, yes. I added the `addUser` function to my OP. The `console.log` in the function shows the correct values for `user`

Comment: @buttonsrtoys `this.users` is not initialized anywhere. You need to do something like `this.users = []` in `Notification`'s constructor.

Comment: Maybe you imported wrong User class or type

Comment: Can you add a link to a reproducible error on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ?

Comment: @Sabareesh Thanks. I just added my constructor

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and I don't see any error, except for a missing `}` at the end of the `Notification` class and a "duplicate identifier" error because [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) is already a part of the standard library. Please create a [mcve] and post the exact error message including the stack trace.

Comment: @Anatoly I followed your advice and reproduced the code on typescriptlang.org and it ran fine there. Something else going on in my code. Will review and post what I learn

Comment: In your addUser() function you call User.toJSON(). Remove it and it should work.

Comment: @Nikolaus In my `addUser()` function I only call `User.toJSON` in `console.log()` so how would that change anything?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Sorry, I‘ve overlooked this. But then the users aren’t of type user. At least partly not. You could check, if user has toJSON and if not log his type...

Comment: Could you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Nikolaus Haven't solved it. I'm using the workaround I mentioned in my OP

Comment: Can you show the code where the notification is initialized?